# getting error 401 unauthorized while accessing WCF service which is on azure

Tags: azure

first I authorized my asp.net application using Azure active directory, then I am  trying to access WCF service which is also on Azure.but getting error 401 unauthorized while calling the service. Is I am missing anything while accessing??

Answer (score 0):

The error implies a 401 HTTP error of access denied.
I’d like to know the sub status code of the 401 error you encountered. 
The 401 error contains the following sub status code:

```
401.1:  Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
401.2:  Access is denied due to server configuration favoring an alternate authentication method. 
401.3:  Access is denied due to an ACL set on the requested resource.
401.4:  Authorization failed by a filter installed on the Web server.
401.5:  Authorization failed by an ISAPI/CGI application.
401.7:  Access denied by URL authorization policy on the Web server.
```

Also, is the asp.net app successfully running locally on IIS to the WCF? Or have you just tried it running on Azure?

You could just create a custom user and make it work, so if you have this problem, you can try the following on your IIS Server:

- Create a windows user;
- Give it read/write/modify/execute/... rights on your WCF data service folder;
- Create a new app pool with .NET 4, integrated mode, and this user;
- On the authentication of the website, enable only the anonymous mode, and set the user to "Application Pool identity".

Or you could try to give "full control" to the "IUSR" account. Maybe it's just that the specific user doesn't have read permission to the disk.

Comment: Yes, my asp.net app running successfully locally on IIS. but after migration of WCF on azure, service is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue, but only because we were accessing the "scm" endpoint. Interesting is that if you create a web app with name "webapp" and you get adress https://webapp.azurewebsites.net/ServiceApplication.svc, you can also access the service over the https://webapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/ServiceApplication.svc. But this address does not allow anonymous access. This error does not appear when you use the address without "scm".